# Google Plus Link Sharing Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus, sharing

I have done code same as Google Plus sharing URL
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/basic-share

Above code redirect me to google plus page, instead of showing POST option while it redirect it on safari.
I tried same url to run on desktop browser it shows POST options even in android browser shows POST option.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this sample method of google sign in, I mean there must be a url handle method like the below method.(May be something similar method available with your SDK).

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
              openURL:(NSURL *)url
    sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
           annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                             sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                    annotation:annotation];
}
```

It may helps you, please check.

Comment: Google Suggest to does not use SDK and they shows warning like below
Google+ Sign-In is deprecated, and is likely to not function as expected. Do not use Google+ Sign-In in new apps. To sign in users with their Google Accounts, use Google Sign-In. See the migration guide to migrate from Google+ Sign-In.

And this is not an answer what i had asked.